# Validate last letters of input field in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I validate the last letters of a link which is posted into my model?

Example:

```
[dropbox.com/dajnkqjknw7/file.mp3]
[dropbox.com/dajnkqjknw7/file.ogg]
[dropbox.com/dajnkqjknw7/file.wav]
```

I just want to check/validate if the last 3 (or 4) letters end on .mp3, .ogg or .wav, how would I use that within my model, use a Regex in combination with validates?

Current beat.rb model:

```
class Beat < ApplicationRecord
  validates :bpm, format: { with: /\A\d+\z/ }, length: { maximum: 3 }
  validates :link, presence: true REGEX IN HERE?
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
validates :link, presence: true, format: { with: /.(mp3|ogv|wav)\z/}
```

where you have a dot `.` and after one of the valid extensions `(mp3|ogv|wav)`, just at the end of the line `\z`

Comment: Exactly what I needed! One more question though: How would I add client-side validation to this? I know I can use pattern: "REGEX", title: "Make sure link ends on .mp3/.ogg/.wav, but what kind of regex do I have to put into the "pattern" attribute?

Thank you so far!

Comment: in theory the same exact regex will work with javascript as expected

Comment: Tried it like this:   , pattern: "/.(mp3|ogg|wav)\z/", title: "Link must end on either .mp3, .wav or .ogg!" and its not working, its always showing the title message, don't know what I am missing..

Comment: I am getting this error:
Pattern attribute value /.(mp3|ogg|wav)\z/ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //.(mp3|ogg|wav)\z//: Invalid escape

Had to record my screen to see this error message since its shown AND gone right after hitting the submit button.

Maybe something about form_for and the pattern attributes requires me to use different regular expressions with different escape characters?

Comment: maybe javascript handles this in another way, try putting in `pattern` this `(.*).(mp3|ogv|wav)$` exactly like that and test if it works. if it doesn't, create another question with this

Comment: Thanks, I got it working and you were right, this did the trick: 
pattern: '.*\.(?:mp3|ogg|wav)$'